# Calculate the difference between two dates in hours and minutes

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, date-time, formula

In SP online in a list, I have a formula that calculates the difference between two dates and outputs the result in Days+Hours+Min.
I was wondering if it's possible to obtain the results only in Hours and Minutes so the result would be 27hrs, 30mins instead of 1day,03hrs, 30mins as on the ex bellow.

[image]

The formula I'm currently using.
`=DATEDIF(Impact_start,Impact_end-(MOD(Impact_start,1)>MOD(Impact_end,1)),"d")&" days, "&TEXT(MOD(Impact_end-Impact_start,1),"hh "" hrs, "" mm "" mins""")`

I already tried `=TEXT([Impact_end]-[Impact_start]), "h:mm")` but sadly it only works for 24h max and I need it to go further than 24h.

Also tried to calculate it in minutes only with `=INT(([Column2]-[Column1])*1440)` but don't know how to convert the output in HH:MM.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=(INT((EndDT-StartDT)*1440)-MOD(INT((EndDT-StartDT)*1440),60))/60&" Hours "&MOD(INT((EndDT-StartDT)*1440),60)&" Minutes"
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks