# Calculating the time between two date/time columns - strange result

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am attempting to calculate the date and time between two date/time columns. I have a formula which I'm running which is giving me a result, but it's not the result I expect and I am not sure why.

See below. The difference between my Start Time and Finish Time is 3 minutes (11:45am to 11:48am), however the formula is returning a result of over 12 minutes?

[image: SharePoint Date Calculation Formula]

[image: SharePoint Columns]

Comment: Try [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286242/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-hours-and-minutes) solution which will work fine in your case

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this formula:

```
==IF(ISBLANK([Finish Time]),"",IF(INT([Finish Time]-[Start Time])>=0,(INT(([Finish Time]-[Start Time])*1440)-MOD(INT(([Finish Time]-[Start Time])*1440),60))/60&" Hours "&MOD(INT(([Finish Time]-[Start Time])*1440),60)&" Minutes","-"&(INT(([Start Time]-[Finish Time])*1440)-MOD(INT(([Start Time]-[Finish Time])*1440),60))/60&" Hours "&"-"&MOD(INT(([Start Time]-[Finish Time])*1440),60)&" Minutes"))
```

[image: the result]

For more information, please refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1056665/negative-time-showing-incorrect-calculation.html

Comment: Hi there - this formula is giving me an error when applied to the calculated column stating it contains syntax which is not supported.

Comment: Sorry, I have edit my answer, please try it.

Comment: Has the problem been solved? If you have any questions, please feel free to contact